# Searching in List of Tuples

Tags: haskell

I have a list of tuples stored in a text file.

```
[(1,"123","Shiva","address #1",77000),(2,"123","Sina","address #2", 1900)]
```

The first element of each `tuple` is `acount_Id` and the second element of each `tuple` is `password` and in the application I tend to read the list from the file and ask for account no and password from the user and look for it in the file. I tried this:

```
x <- readFile "database.txt" 
y <- tuples x 
let account  = [(a,b)|(a,b,c,d,e) <- y, ac_no ==a , pass == b]
```

`tuples` is a function that takes a string and give output of IO [(AccNo, Pass, Name, Address, Balance)] data type

Any idea how can I improve this process by using higher order function instead of list processing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just some general style advice: if you're using tuples that complex, you should consider replacing them with a dedicated type. This makes your intentions clearer. If you use record syntax, it also makes extracting fields easier.

Comment: if you google "stringly typed" you can find background reading about better and worse data representations in different languages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function `lookup` which has the type signature:

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

But this is only defined for pairs.

One option would be to use types to specialize to get this arrangement.

```
data UserDetails = UserDetails {
  password :: String
  address  :: String
}
```

And define your list as `(String,UserDetails)` pairs, then you'd be able to use the `lookup` function.  Putting your data into types (rather than just lots of strings) is in general a really good thing to do anyway, so I think this would be good.

If you did want to use a higher-order function, take a look at `find`, which will return the first of a list matching a pattern.

Something like

```
type UserDataAssociation = (String,String,String,String,String)

findMatchingAssociations :: [UserDataAssociation] -> String -> Maybe UserDataAssociation
findMatchingAssociations xs password = find (\(pw,a) -> pw == password) xs
```

Comment: but if the list gets too large, wouldn't that be a time consuming effort?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean in terms of time-consuming?  In what regard?

Comment: it was about redefining the whole list into list of pairs  but I get the find solution now.

Comment: I guess adding types can be lots of effort, but it's the raison d'etre of Haskell.  Use the types, the function signatures follow and the implementation works itself out (well, not quite that easy :P)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm trying to find a way to use the "find" with two condition.

Comment: You can just extend the predicate out `(\pw,a) -> pw == password && a == ("a","b","c","d"))` or use a function of your choice with the same signature.

Comment: I see. I will try this one. with this logic I can even add more conditions. I like it.